# Objects dissapear when rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects

I am trying my hand at making the millennium falcon. However, when I go to render, several objects that I had separated from the main mesh didn't render.

Everything is set to render in the outliner, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here it is in the 3d View:

[image: 3d View]

All objects show up in the 3d veiwport when rendering mode is turned on.

Here it is rendered:

[image: Rendered]

Here is my blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it is only showing up in local view, not global view (notice the lack of layers shown in the 3d view ribbon bar).

The problem is that those object(s) are not applied to any layers.

[image]

---

To fix this, select each object and assign one of the rendered layers to it.

[image]

---

By the way, to switch between global and local view, hit <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> or go to View > View Global/Local.